# jQuery ajax POST to ASP.NET WebMatrix action

Tags: jquery, asp.net, post, webmatrix

I am trying to submit a login request using jQuery

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/File/Location',
   type: 'POST',
   data: 'username=email@you.com&password=secret',
   success: function (data){
    console.log(data);
   },
   error: function (xhr, status, error){
    console.warn(error);
   }
 });
```

But when I get the request on the server-side (ASP.NET WebMatrix/Razor engine) the Request object is empty

```
Request = @Request.Form

if(IsPost){
 //Aunthentication logic
}
```

I have tried a few combinations of the ajax request but no luck. Anyone have a clue?

Thanks

Comment: Try using an object instead of a string in the data parameter: `data: { username: 'email@you.com', password: 'secret' }` and see if that works. Let jQuery format the query string for you.

Comment: @Chad both are accepted and shouldn't do any difference. "The data option can contain either a query string of the form key1=value1&key2=value2, or a map of the form {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}. If the latter form is used, the data is converted into a query string using jQuery.param() before it is sent."

Comment: @Daok I'm well aware of that, I have had issues with using a string before however; hence the suggestion.

Comment: Can you provide the ASP.NET class or at least the method

Comment: @Chad I first tried using an object but that didnt work

Comment: @Daok There isnt a code behind .cs file with an asp.net class that i can find. In webmatrix all the files have a .cshtml extension and I cant see a way to get to the controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No changes are required to your jQuery code.

```
var password = Request["password"];
var username = Request["username"];
if(IsPost){
    //Do your thing
}
```

You could also reference the individual form fields via their full form:

```
var password = Request.Form["password"];
```

Comment: This is what I thought would work but it isnt working. The Request object has no parameters in it. Not in Request or in Request.Form

Comment: The code above should go in a file called Location.cshtml in a folder called File. It worked fine for me.

Comment: You're right Mike. I was using a proxy to avoid Cross-Domain request restrictions and I think it was blocking my parameters getting through. Instead I am running Chrome with web security disabled and it works.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UserFormInformation{
    public string Username{ get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(UserFormInformation info)
{
    //...
}



$.ajax({
   url: '/File/Location/Login',
   type: 'POST',
   data: 'username=email@you.com&password=secret',
   success: function (data){
    console.log(data);
   },
   error: function (xhr, status, error){
    console.warn(error);
   }
 });
```

I would do this to explore further. First, be sure to have the HttpPost (which doesn't seem to be here or not in the original question. From here, you can use directly a class instead of a global variable. We do not have the signature of the method you are using.

Also, into the Javascript, be sure you call the good method.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Doak but I think your answer assumes that I have a code behind file to implement the class logic but i dont. It is just a .cshtml file. Of course if you know how I could implement this in webmatrix can you please point that out?